# Meaning Of Sukanya, Rishi Chyavan, Ashwini Kumars Story

Tags: saint, ashwini-kumaras

Have often heard the story of Sukanya disrupting Rishi Chyavan’s meditation, then marrying him. After which the Ashwini Kumars make Rishi Chyavan young again by bathing in a lake which is like the fountain of youth. So Sukanya is given a more age appropriate husband, young guy.

Is there some figurative meaning, or deeper message in this story ? Many of these very well known tales seem to have that, not sure what it is here.